# Discord.py error in callable prefix: takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, arguments, typeerror, discord.py

I'm using the discord.py library and I'm trying to make a callable prefix.
However, I'm getting this error whenever a message is posted.
The `prefix_callable` function should return two possible prefixes, but it throws an error instead.

`TypeError: prefix_callable() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`

Maybe It's a dumb error, but I'm new to Python and can't figure this one out. Thank you!

This is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import json
import bot_modules
from bot_modules import misc
import Utilities
from Utilities import manageDataStores
botconfigf = open("./Utilities/botconfig.json", "r")
botconfig = json.load(botconfigf)

def prefix_callable(bot, message):
    return "!", "@()"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix_callable, case_insensitive = True)

@commands.command
async def info (ctx):
    await ctx.send("ayy")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ADAB is online!")

client.run("---")
```

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you using?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  Discord.py version `0.16.12`

Comment: I can't reproduce this on either the `async` or `rewrite` branches.  Could you post a `MCVE` that includes a basic command?  Be sure to remove your private token from anything you post.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  Edited

Comment: If I chenge `@commands.command` to `@client.command()`, that works perfectly as `rewrite` branch code. It should fail for a different reason in `0.16.12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I wasn't using the rewrite and this stopped erroring in the rewrite.

Just use the rewrite to avoid this.